# how to configure the microphone array of Matrix Creator

Tags: matrix-creator

Try to use the microphone array of Matrix Creator via JS, noticed the below JS testing code on github, but 
Any idea of the right configurations for these settings? many thanks

```
// setup gain for all microphones
micarray_cfg.set_gain(32)

// setup a sound source perpendicular to the MATRIX Creator
micarray_cfg.set_azimutal_angle(0)
micarray_cfg.set_polar_angle(0)
micarray_cfg.set_radial_distance_mm(1000)
micarray_cfg.set_sound_speed_mmseg(341 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sean here from the MATRIX team. This is from the protobuf file that defines the mic array parameters and defines the inputs for the different options.

```
// Microphone Array params
message MicArrayParams {
  // gain for all microphones
  int32 gain = 1;

  // Spherical coordinates for beamforming (azimutal_angle,
  // polar_angle, radial_distance_mm).
  //
  // azimutal angle (must lie between -pi/2 an pi/2)
  float azimutal_angle  = 2;

  // polar angle (must lie between -pi/2 an pi/2)
  float polar_angle = 3;

  // distance from the center of the MATRIX Creator to the sound source.
  float radial_distance_mm = 4;

  // sound speed in mm/seg  
  float sound_speed_mmseg = 5;
}
```

From:

https://github.com/matrix-io/protocol-buffers/blob/master/malos/driver.proto

Comment: thanks Sean, I have played with those configuration, I can tell radial_distance_mm can make a lot differences on the mic array performance, but still not sure how to configure azimutal_angle and polar_angle. I found the below picture, can you help explain how to apply it to Matrix Creator. And if I am using Channel 8, are these configurations will be applied to all those 7 mics? Many thanks, [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAncq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAncq.png)